# QString to const std::string

Tags: c++, string, constants, qstring

I want to assign the value in QString to a const std::string

```
QString qfile("some value");
```

this is the const std::string variable

```
const std::string file
```

The code that I m using

```
file = qfile.toStdString();
```

above codes works fine for a normal std::string . But there is some problem because of the keyword 'const'. How do I solve it ?

Comment: Any work around? Yes: if you want to change something, don't declare it `const`. Or, if you want it to be immutable, then don't try to change it.

Comment: Possibly a const_cast but what is the logic that requires you to assign to a const variable?  Perhaps you should update that rather than applying a work around?

Comment: @Stefan: `const_cast` would make it compile, but trying to modify a `const` object gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: note that `Qt::toStdString()` by default converts the string to Latin1 encoding, and because of that any characters which cant be represented in Latin1 will be lost. If you use that `std::string` for filenames, you wont be able to handle files with names containing special characters. You can use `const std::string file = qFile.toUtf8().constData();` intstead. But on Windows you wont be able to use the `std::string` for file operations anyway, because Windows does not support UTF8 properly.

Comment: @VihaanVerma: Why did you declare it `const` in the first place ? We really need to know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the assignment operator to initialize the `std::string` object but rather initialize the variable directly.

```
const std::string file = qfile.toStdString();
```

That aside, please make sure that you're aware of what encoding `QString::toStdString()` uses; unlike `QString`, `std::string` is encoding-agnostic (it's a string of bytes, not characters).

Comment: or `const std::string file( qfile.toStdString() );`

Comment: (insert here the usual comment about most vexing parse)

Comment: the variable is already being used in code. I just want to update its content.

Comment: @VihaanVerma: you can't, otherwise `const` would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Constants** are expressions with a fixed value.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of the `const` by making copy of the return value of `toStdString()`:

```
QString str("text");
std::string std_str(str.toStdString());
```